# Deployable application on Jetty, JBoss, and TomCat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jboss, jetty

I have the following requirement, for a Java Spring MVC application:

> It must be possible to run the web application from command line by using `jetty server` and it must be possible to deploy it to other possible application servers (Tomcat, JBoss) as well.

I use Eclipse, and I know it uses Tomcat, but how I can configure the `pom.xml` in a way that the final application is deployable on JBoss, and Jetty?

Comment: pom.xml is about Maven, dependencies, and packaging.  It won't know anything about running on a particular platform.  I'd recommend that you look into Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Create a spring mvc project as described [this blog](https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/)

In your pom.xml keep your packaging as war

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Configure a maven-jetty-plugin from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-maven-plugin.html)

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
</plugin>
```

You can run jetty by using mvn jetty:run from console.

You can build your application using maven command, such as mvn clean install
which will create a war file now you can deploy this in your jboss deployments folder.

Hope this helps you out.